# MongoDB fetch values of ObjectId Array

Tags: mongodb, database-design, objectid, database

I am creating a simple application which will track every time a player kills another player. This means that when they kill a player, the killed player will be added to their `userarray` (containing all the players they have killed) which can then be later used for statistics, etc. The problem with storing just the usernames as string values in the array is that it'd take more space and I'd take longer to fetch the other data.

The problem I am having is I'm unsure how to store the player's kills. I need to be able to grab the `userarray` key, get each `username`, and then display it.

Would this cause lag as it has to fetch every single user in that array? Is there a way I can get the `userarray` with all of the values already parsed by the query?

Structure for the user's collection (along with `ip`, `date`, etc);

[image]

Structure for the second collection;

[image]

[image]

And I am trying to end up with data like this;

[image]

Comment: Well you ended up with no data. the question is not complete!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this probably could have done with some more explanation than the screenshots provided, you seem to be struggling with a core concept of schema design in MongoDB which we can address in an answer.

As you point out, you have a `userarray` field in a document that contains a list of `ObjectId` references. Presumably these refer to documents that either sit elsewhere in the collection or in another collection of their own.

The big problem with this is that, "MongoDB does not do Joins", and as you are expecting to get "properties" out of the referenced document, then that is not going to happen. Certainly not in any easy way.

So what you *probably* want is [embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/), where all the data you want to reference is actually contained *within* the parent document you are retrieving. But then again according to your usage needs you may want something else. For this it would be recommended that you spend some time reading the [Data Modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) section from the MongoDB documentation. This discusses various approaches and will help you gain an understanding.

In the event that you really think after all that reading that references are really what you want, then it would be advised to [go to google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb%20ODM), in order to search out the library for your language that will give you some assistance with this.

At any rate, general discussions are too broad. Best do the reading, try things out, and then ask questions about specific issues you have.